# oci_parse giving error when using php variable

Tags: php, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to build a string to pass an array into oracle using oci.
If I write the string it works fine, but if I pass it as a variable it gives an error.

This works fine:

```
$c = oci_pconnect ( $config ['db'] ['username'], $config ['db'] ['password'], $config ['db'] ['hostspec'] );


        try {
$llamado = "DECLARE V_DNA_ARRAY M6_TEMP_DNA_TAB_TYPE:=M6_TEMP_DNA_TAB_TYPE();BEGIN V_DNA_ARRAY.extend(3); V_DNA_ARRAY(1) := O_M6_TEMP_DNA('91','92','93','94','95'); V_DNA_ARRAY(2) := O_M6_TEMP_DNA('96','97','98','99','910'); V_DNA_ARRAY(3) := O_M6_TEMP_DNA('911','912','913','914','915'); SINTRA.PKG_MEDULA.P_INSERT_TEMP_DNA ( V_DNA_ARRAY );END;";
            $s = oci_parse ( $c, $llamado );
            $r = oci_execute ( $s);


        } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            var_dump ( $r );
            var_dump ( $e->$d->getMessage () );
            die ( 'STOP' );
        }
```

But if I do this (because values will change) it gives me:

> Warning: oci_parse() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\cph_donante\inside\action\gsilva\insert.php
>   on line 153
>
> Warning: oci_execute() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\cph_donante\inside\action\gsilva\insert.php on line
>   154

```
 $c = oci_pconnect ( $config ['db'] ['username'], $config ['db'] ['password'], $config ['db'] ['hostspec'] );


        try {

        $llamado = '"DECLARE V_DNA_ARRAY M6_TEMP_DNA_TAB_TYPE:=M6_TEMP_DNA_TAB_TYPE();BEGIN ';
$llamado .= 'V_DNA_ARRAY.extend('.count($c1).'); ';
foreach ($c1 as $c => $v){
$llamado .= 'V_DNA_ARRAY('.($c + 1).') := O_M6_TEMP_DNA('.$v.'); ';
}
$llamado .= 'SINTRA.PKG_MEDULA.P_INSERT_TEMP_DNA ( V_DNA_ARRAY );END;"';


            $s = oci_parse ( $c, $llamado );
            $r = oci_execute ( $s );


        } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            var_dump ( $r );
            var_dump ( $e->$d->getMessage () );
            die ( 'STOP' );
        }
```

Can you tell me how it works?

Answer (score 0):

At first look it appears that you have your colons on the wrong side of the equals sign in your statement.

Here is the link to the php doc on oci_parse: [oci_parse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-parse.php)

Also, you may want to take a look at oci_bind functions to bind variables to your statement before executing.

In answer to your question of wanting to know how it works, my best answer is read the documentation. PHP docs are pretty well written (imo) and there are examples of implementation too. I would look there for how it works.